# What Text Classification algorithms I can use to classify customer chat messages?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, deep-learning, google-natural-language

I am working on classifying customer chat messages into 5 categories. The example of categories are - Login, SSL etc. For Instance, if customer is having login issues, the message may read something like this - I am having a login issue or my login is not working... We have to take into account misspelling, mentioning multiple classified keywords (eg: I just upgraded my SSL but now I am having issue with login) etc.

Are there models/apis out there that I can use to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is quite broad, because your problem is essentially about text classification, and in literature it had been faced from most of NLP classification algorithms, so there are much more options (and maybe in your case better) than deep learning. But if you want to use deep learning you need to consider not only the architecture (simple multilayer, convolutional, LSTM, etc.), but the amount of labeled data you need for a good traning (and what about unsupervised algorithms for text classification?).

Then, independent of the approach you decide, I strongly recommend you check word embeddings algorithms (pretrained or built using your own data), specially those similar to [fasttext](https://fasttext.cc/), because will let you [deal with misspelling words](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/faqs.html#why-does-fasttext-produce-vectors-even-for-unknown-words).

I hope this helps

Comment: fasttext worked in my scenario. It is very powerful and super fast text classifier.